# Create a stacked bar chart

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, charts, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart ,
But I'm getting an error in the lines that has  ".Series " (How to define the  Series ? )

```
    SeriesChartType chart1 = new SeriesChartType();

    // Populate series data
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
    {
        chart1.Series["LightBlue"].Points.AddY(random.Next(45, 95));
    }

    // Set chart type
    chart1.Series["LightBlue"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedArea100;

    // Show point labels
    chart1.Series["LightBlue"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

    // Disable X axis margin
    chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.IsMarginVisible = false;

    // Set the first two series to be grouped into Group1
    chart1.Series["LightBlue"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group1";
    chart1.Series["Gold"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group1";

    // Set the last two series to be grouped into Group2
    chart1.Series["Red"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group2";
    chart1.Series["DarkBlue"]["StackedGroupName"] = "Group2";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code above seems to be from the MS Chart Samples application. Looking at the MS example stacked bar chart on screen, and the source code above, its obvious that the sample code is inadequate and does not show us how to do stacked bar charts.

You can either programmatically create and attach a series:

```
Series s1 = new Series("LightBlue");
s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar100;
chart1.Series.Add(s1);
```

or alternatively, you can define the series in your ASPX file and simple add Y values to each series in the code behind:

```
Random  random = new Random();
for(int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 10; pointIndex++)
{
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(45, 95),0));
    Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(5, 75),0));
    Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(5, 95),0));
    Chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(35, 95),0));
}
```

In the MS Chart Samples web solution, have a look at

```
/ChartTypes/BarColumnCharts/Stacked/stackedchart.aspx
```

it should have all you need.